# Inheritable @IBInspectable var in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

Suppose **I create an `@IBInspectable` variable in a base `@IBDesignable` class**.

Now, the attribute doesn't make the property inspectable in a derived class. That's clearly by design — you want to be able to create a derived class that sets base attributes according to its own logic and prohibits the user from touching them.

However, suppose **I want to make the same attributes inspectable in the derived class**. The problem is, `@IBInspectable` is only used with variable definitions, so it seems to require me to redefine the variable, even though the definition has already been provided (that's where I miss Objective-C: you could change class interface without touching the implementation provided you knew what you were doing).

This has the following drawback: you can't override a base stored variable, and you need to provide an explicit getter and setter. Therefore, the cleanest code I came up with is this:

```
// derived class
@IBInspectable override var borderWidth: CGFloat {
get {
    return super.borderWidth
}
set {
    super.borderWidth = newValue
}
}

// base class
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
set {
    layer.borderWidth = newValue
    // this can be a very complicated setter, of course
}
get {
    return layer.borderWidth
    // this can be a very complicated getter, of course
}
}
```

**Question: is there a shorthand syntax to do that?**

*(If not, and if other people like the idea, I'll probably file a radar for Apple's magicians.)*

Comment: That sounds like [a great radar to file](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Does it work if you provide only a property observer (e.g. empty `didSet`)?

Comment: @rickster, oh, thanks, didn't know I can omit getter and setter. That's already better!

Comment: @rickster, actually no, now it complains that the base variable is not initialized and my attempts at further experiments mostly end with compiler crashes.

Comment: Well, so much for that curiosity, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: as of Xcode 6 beta 3 this is fixed: Interface Builder sees also inspectable properties in the superclass**

There is a [question](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998866#998866) in the Apple Forums for this issue.

For Xcode 6 beta 2 and below: shorten the code using `didSet` as follows and it should work:

```
// derived class
@IBInspectable override var borderWidth: CGFloat { didSet{} }

// base class
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
set {
    layer.borderWidth = newValue
    // this can be a very complicated setter, of course
}
get {
    return layer.borderWidth
    // this can be a very complicated getter, of course
}
}
```